# Structured array drops field-titles when being indexed with field-name

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, field

Is the following behaviour of numpy (v1.13.1) a bug or by design?

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>a = np.zeros((1,), dtype=[(('title 1', 'x'), '|i1'), (('title 2', 'y'), '>f4')])

>>>a.dtype.descr
[(('title 1', 'x'), '|i1'), (('title 2', 'y'), '>f4')]

>>>a[['y','x']].dtype.descr
[('y', '>f4'), ('x', '|i1')]

# I would have expected the previous expression to have returned this instead: 
# [(('title 2', 'y'), '>f4'), (('title 1', 'x'), '|i1')]
```

Note how the field-**title** of a field disappears whenever indexing an array with field-names. (I really mean the field-**title**, not the field-**name** !)

Is there any workaround for this problem?

---

### Addendum: Why titles are a cool feature

Since it seems that many people consider titles should be (or even already are) deprecated, I'll try to advocate why they are a great feature of dtypes:

I acquire large data-series with dozens of fields and find it very useful to have concise field-names for the sake of code readability. Titles allow me to additionally have field documentation in human readable form, without sacrificing conciseness of the names.

It is especially handy that both, names and titles, are being assigned where the data originated in the first place and just gets passed along through the pipeline: acquisition-->processing-->storage...
Losing titles along that pipeline is especially inconvenient, because they tend to be the more useful the further down the pipeline, e.g. numpy arrays that have been serialized for storage or exchange: It just takes these two lines of code to get ***any*** ndarray persisted to database or sent over the wire:

```
serialized_array.dtype = repr(numpy_array.dtype.descr)
serialized_array.buffer = base64.b64encode(numpy_array.tostring())
```

And any consumer/receiver of that data has the benefit of a fully documented dtype in readable plain text, where the titles document important aspects of a field, like the physical unit (e.g.: mm or inches?)

Recreating a numpy array that has been serialized as shown above is done in also two lines of code, with each field's documentation being included, too:

```
bytes_buffer = base64decode(serialized_array.buffer)
numpy_array = np.frombuffer(bytes_buffer, dtype=eval(serialized_array.dtype))
```

Also note how the existence of titles does in fact allow the use of even conciser field-names, e.g. instead of

```
('PosX_mm', '>f4')
```

you can have

```
(('Position along X-axis [mm]', 'x'), '>f4')
```

The latter looks cumbersome to declare, but consider the usages, e.g. in pyplot:

```
plt.plot(a['x'])
plt.ylabel(a.dtype.fields['x'][2])
```

Note how this is not only quite readable, but also reduces the risk of having to refactor all occurrences of the field-name 'x', just because the lack of documentation/titles forced you to change the field-name in order to avoid misunderstandings. Title strings can be modified at the spot where the data originates and changes just propagate through the pipeline without having to change any further source-code.

Comment: interesting a[['x']].dtype.descr .... [('x', '|i1')]

Comment: Indeed interesting, @NaN, but what you are pointing out seems plausible behaviour to me: a['x'] returns a non-structured array and a[['x']] returns a structured array. Just to avoid confusion: This is unrelated to my original question. ;-)

Comment: I think it is being consistent... a = np.arange(3) ... a.dtype.descr => [('', '<i4')]

Comment: @NaN: You are referring to the field-**name**. My question is about the field-**title**. I think I'll simplify my example to just focus on the structured-array case, which is the one I consider not to be behaving as expected. You are right that slicing just a single field out of the structured-array returns a non-structured array and hence it's kind of consistent to drop its field-name and field-title.

Comment: dt = a.dtype ... b = a[['x', 'y']].view(dtype=dt) .... b.dtype.desc => [(('title 1', 'x'), '|i1'), (('title 2', 'y'), '>f4')]  is the workaround... without examining the exact code on GitHub, I suspect that the slice only brings over the required dtype parameters and drops the optional ones.  I would expect that to be the default option and the workaround for specifying the dtype to reflect the parent's dtype is acceptable since it would be an exception given optional parameters are just that.... optional

Comment: The workaround you are proposing is only working if my indexes are identical to a.dtype.names, which is not really a useful example for indexing; that is just creating a view which is identical to the original array. Note how my example reverses the field order when indexing, to illustrate that aspect. And in my interpretation it is "optional" to specify titles when defining the original array, but it is an unexpected behaviour to lose explicitly defined titles when just slicing/indexing that same array.

Comment: Since it is a view, you have the option to specify a dtype https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had reported this as an [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9625) and Allan Haldane has [fixed](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/9f27418f48ada95a1cf19c98a8d1116f97f86ec5) it.

Answer (score 1):

So your `dtype` is:

```
In [68]: dt3=np.dtype([(('title 1', 'x'), '|i1'), (('title 2', 'y'), '>f4')])
In [69]: dt3
Out[69]: dtype([(('title 1', 'x'), 'i1'), (('title 2', 'y'), '>f4')])
In [70]: dt3.descr
Out[70]: [(('title 1', 'x'), '|i1'), (('title 2', 'y'), '>f4')]
In [71]: dt3.fields
Out[71]: 
mappingproxy({'title 1': (dtype('int8'), 0, 'title 1'),
              'title 2': (dtype('>f4'), 1, 'title 2'),
              'x': (dtype('int8'), 0, 'title 1'),
              'y': (dtype('>f4'), 1, 'title 2')})
In [72]: dt3.names
Out[72]: ('x', 'y')
```

In the documentation, `titles` are normally provided in this format:

```
In [79]: np.dtype({'names':['x','y'],
                   'formats':['|i1','>f4'],
                   'titles':['title 1','title 2']})
Out[79]: dtype([(('title 1', 'x'), 'i1'), (('title 2', 'y'), '>f4')])
```

Titles are rare feature, and thus more likely to contain rough edges, things that don't match users expectations.

So what's the use of titles?  One possibility is they give an alternative field access key:

```
In [82]: a['x']
Out[82]: array([0], dtype=int8)
In [83]: a['title 1']
Out[83]: array([0], dtype=int8)
```

Note that in the `fields` dictionary, there are entries for the titles as well as the names.

Indexing with field name or title returns an array with a simpler dtype, in this case a `native` dtype:

```
In [86]: a['title 1'].dtype
Out[86]: dtype('int8')
In [87]: a['title 1'].dtype.descr
Out[87]: [('', '|i1')]
In [88]: a['title 1'].dtype.fields
In [94]: a['title 1'].dtype.isnative
Out[94]: True
In [96]: a['title 1'].dtype.type
Out[96]: numpy.int8
In [97]: dt3.type
Out[97]: numpy.void
```

Compound dtypes can also be nested, e.g.

```
In [98]: np.dtype([('foo',dt3)])
Out[98]: dtype([('foo', [(('title 1', 'x'), 'i1'), (('title 2', 'y'), '>f4')])])
```

and indexing this with 'foo' will produce a `dt3` dtype.

In any case indexing with a field name or title steps down a level in the nesting, and does not preserve offsets or titles.  Those are properties of the parent dtype, `dt3`, not of the sub-dtype.

Indexing with a list creates a new `dtype`, with a name, but no title:

```
In [102]: a[['x']]
Out[102]: 
array([(0,)],
      dtype=[('x', 'i1')])
In [103]: a[['x','title 1']]
Out[103]: 
array([(0, 0)],
      dtype=[('x', 'i1'), ('title 1', 'i1')])
```

I may not have added any new information, but it's clarified, to me at least, the role of titles.

If you need titles in the new view, then you'll have to provide them explicitly. For example:

```
In [113]: dt3x = np.dtype([(('title 1', 'x'), '|i1')])
In [114]: a['x'].view(dt3x)
Out[114]: 
array([(0,)],
      dtype=[(('title 1', 'x'), 'i1')])
In [115]: _['title 1']
Out[115]: array([0], dtype=int8)
```

---

Speaking of nested dtypes, we can preserve 'title 1' if it is nested

```
In [117]: dt4=np.dtype([('x', np.dtype([('title 1','|i1')])), ('y', np.dtype([('
     ...: title 2', '>f4')]))])
In [118]: dt4
Out[118]: dtype([('x', [('title 1', 'i1')]), ('y', [('title 2', '>f4')])])
In [119]: b = np.zeros((2,), dt4)
In [120]: b
Out[120]: 
array([((0,), ( 0.,)), ((0,), ( 0.,))],
      dtype=[('x', [('title 1', 'i1')]), ('y', [('title 2', '>f4')])])
In [121]: b['x']
Out[121]: 
array([(0,), (0,)],
      dtype=[('title 1', 'i1')])
In [122]: b['x']['title 1']
Out[122]: array([0, 0], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive review of how dtype and titles behave. Seems I'll have to manage the dtype myself on each an every indexing operation along my data processing stack.

Comment: You ask "So what's the use of titles?". This is my use-case: I acquire large data-series with dozens of fields and use titles to document a human readable description and the physical unit (e.g.: mm or inches?). Titles are useful as e.g. axis labels of charts, or as documentation whenever exchanging data with other people. It is great to have concise field-names that improve code readability and also have extensive documentation in human readable form, both already defined where the data originated in the first place. It's therefore a pity to lose it along the way.